# terraform unable to create AD VM because public ip is missing

Tags: active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The code below is aiming to create a server as AD server, basically remote exec provisioner

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-grpprd-ad" {
  count                 = "${var.count_ad_vm}"
  name                  = "${var.ad_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-grpprd-core.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-grpprd-core.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-grpprd-ad.id}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-grpprd-ad.*.id, count.index)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.ad_vm_size}"

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
        connection {
            host        = "${var.ad_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}"
            type        = "winrm"
            user        = "${var.username}"
            password    = "${var.password}"
            port        = 5985
            https       = true
            timeout     = "5m"
        }

        inline = [
            "powershell.exe Install-windowsfeature -name AD-Domain-Services –IncludeManagementTools",
            "powershell.exe Install-ADDSForest –DomainName contoso.com "
        ]
   }
}
```

However, I get error as below:

```
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3128856Z [0m[0mazurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via WinRM...
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3130332Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Host: grpprdad01
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3130709Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Port: 5985
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3131103Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   User: scmadmin
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3132001Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Password: true
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3132346Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   HTTPS: true
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3134155Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Insecure: false
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3134533Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   NTLM: false
2019-07-22T04:08:29.3135134Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   CACert: false
2019-07-22T04:08:33.4976351Z [0m[1mazurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0]: Still creating... [7m50s elapsed][0m[0m
2019-07-22T04:08:43.4977940Z [0m[1mazurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0]: Still creating... [8m0s elapsed][0m[0m
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3173656Z [0m[0mazurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via WinRM...
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3174438Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Host: grpprdad01
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3174748Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Port: 5985
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3175063Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   User: scmadmin
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3175530Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Password: true
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3175807Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   HTTPS: true
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3176136Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   Insecure: false
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3176425Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   NTLM: false
2019-07-22T04:08:49.3176714Z azurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0] (remote-exec):   CACert: false
2019-07-22T04:08:53.4979726Z [0m[1mazurerm_virtual_machine.tf-vm-grpprd-ad[0]: Still creating... [8m10s elapsed][0m[0m
2019-07-22T04:08:58.2186501Z [0m[0m
2019-07-22T04:08:58.2455285Z [31m
2019-07-22T04:08:58.2456623Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mtimeout - last error: unknown error Post https://grpprdad01:5985/wsman: dial tcp: lookup grpprdad01 on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host[0m
2019-07-22T04:08:58.2457076Z
```

So My suspicion is host value in remote-exec block is incorrect?

How to have the issue resolved so two VM's (AD Cluster) can be created successfully by terraform?

Comment: Maybe you can add the secret to the VM and try it again.

Comment: But I think the issue is the IP is not the IP of VM

Comment: I made the test and also do not succeed even if I can connect through the Powershell with the FQDN or public IP.

Comment: I mean it's not the issue of the public IP, the issue is other things.

Comment: So any other way to execute PowerShell command on the newly provisioned? Maybe packer can install the AD component?

Comment: I do not have the experience that uses the terraform to create a connection for winrm. Maybe you can take at this [document](https://www.oipapio.com/question-353928).

Comment: Great!, I will follow the doco and see how it goes.